# How to lock keyboard / trackpad on macbook (pro)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I lock the mouse and keyboard but see the screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/214221/how-can-i-lock-the-mouse-and-keyboard-but-see-the-screen)

Hi

Our toddlers want to watch something on youtube once in a while, but they can't refrain from typing and using the trackpad whilst watching. So this can get quite stressful for all of us, as they click away everything. Same for photo enjoyment.

I have been looking for a trick or a special app that allows me to lock either keyboard / trackpad or both, as I can't just unplug them. I could use the iphone remote or a mouse to steer everything while the main keyboard / trackpad are locked.

Any hints? I wouldnt mind spending some $ onshareware, but no luck yet.

Would be great

Urs

Comment: The author of [Keyboard Cleaner](http://jan.prima.de/~jan/plok/archives/48-Keyboard-Cleaner.html) writes that he cannot disable mouse and keyboard alone and keep the desktop.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll contact him and ask if this is still the case... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Plug laptop into external monitor or tv and close the thing.

Comment: I don't have / don't want such a thing at home...